# Primary key no defined access database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ms-access-2007

I am developping an application in wpf. I have to work with an existing database in Access.
I used the ORM EntityFramework. 
My problem is : in the database, its exists a table with no primary key so I can't add any values in this table.
The Error I get is: no primary key defined. I can change the definition of the table.
How can I solve my problem ? thx

Comment: Adding an autonumber primary key to that table should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thx u ! I am going to test it ;)

Answer (score 2):

So as to createy a primary key before you begin you must know that 
a table can contain only one PRIMARY KEY constraint.
All columns defined within a PRIMARY KEY constraint must be defined as NOT NULL. If nullability is not specified, all columns participating in a PRIMARY KEY constraint have their nullability set to NOT NULL.
Security
Permissions
Creating a new table with a primary key requires CREATE TABLE permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the table is being created.
Creating a primary key in an existing table requires ALTER permission on the table.